# views and urlpattern: problems with import?

Tags: python, django, url

I'm following a tutorial but I have some problems...

My `url.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'TasksManager.views.index.page', name="public_index"),
    url(r'^connection-TasksManager$', 'TasksManager.views.connection.page',
        name="public_connection"),
    ...
]
```

TasksManager and views are directories, index and connection are files .py and page are def inside those files. I don't know why the tutorial don't make me write the views in views.py

Anyway it give me an `import error: No module named ' TasksManager'`
I don't know what import in url.py...

`from . import TasksManager` ? (it give error)

`import TasksManager.index` ? (maybe it don't do nothing)

My directory structure:

```
Work_Manager
|__manage.py
|__TasksManager
|      |_ __init__.py
|      |_admin.py
|      |_apps.py
|      |_models.py
|      |_views.py (empty)
|      |_views
|          |_ __init__.py
|          |_index.py
|          |_connection.py
|          |_...
|__Work_Manager
       |_ __init__.py
       |_database.db
       |_settings.py
       |_url.py
```

If I put `index.py`, `connection.py` in TaskManager directory and change the url in `url(r'^$', 'TasksManager.connection.page', name="public_connection"),` (I removed .views. ) the address works but the links in my template (html) dont: `<a href="{% url 'public_connection' %}">Connection</a>` and gives the same error `import error: No module named ' TasksManager'`

Also it give this warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got TasksManager.views.index.page). Pass the callable instead.

Thank you for your help

PS: I'm using Python 3.4 and Django 1.9

Complete Traceback:

```
    Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 1.9.5
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'TasksManager']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\Work_manager\TasksManager\templates\en\public\index.html, error at line 58
   No module named ' TasksManager'   48 :       {% for city in array_city %}
   49 :         <li>
   50 :           {{ city }}
   51 :         </li>
   52 :       {% endfor %}
   53 :     </ul>
   54 : 
   55 :   <article>
   56 :     Hello world ! <br />
   57 :     <!--<a href="connection">Connection</a>-->
   58 :     <a href=" {% url 'public_connection' %} ">Connection</a>
   59 :     <a href="{% url 'create_developer' %}">Create developer</a>
   60 :     <a href="{% url 'create_supervisor' %}">Create supervisor</a>
   61 :     <a href="{% url 'create_project' %}">Create project</a>
   62 :   </article>
   63 : {% endblock %}
   64 : 

Traceback:

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  115.         mod = import_module(mod_name)

File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  109.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

During handling of the above exception (No module named ' TasksManager'), another exception occurred:

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\Work_manager\TasksManager\views\index.py" in page
  39.     return render(request, 'en/public/index.html', locals())

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  97.         return template.render(context, request)

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  95.             return self.template.render(context)

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  206.                     return self._render(context)

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  69.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  499.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  600.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  448.             self._populate()

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  334.                 lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in callback
  255.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)

File "C:\Python34\lib\functools.py" in wrapper
  448.                 result = user_function(*args, **kwds)

File "c:\Python34\Scripts\Work_Manager\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  121.             if submod and not module_has_submodule(import_module(parentmod), submod):

File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  109.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named ' TasksManager'
```

Comment: Your directory is named `TaskManager` but you're calling it as `TasksManager` Also, what kind of error does your `<a href...>` throw?

Comment: A digit error... my directory is TasksManager. The error of my <a href...> is the same No module named ' TasksManager'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have the `__init__.py` file in your folders. This can be just an empty file.

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the
>   directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent
>   directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally
>   hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In
>   the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can
>   also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__`
>   variable, described later

I believe your imports should be

```
from TaskManager import index
```

or

```
import TaskManager
```

[more ...](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: thanks @v1k45 I didn't realize that the __ had been dropped on copy paste. No idea why.

Comment: it happened because double underscores stand for bold/ strong text formatting in markdown

Comment: @e4c5 There are `__init__.py` (empty). I edited my directory structure

Comment: Nothing yet... I add both import and I don't see any change... it give the same error. I added the traceback. PS I use Python 3.4 (your link is for python 2.x)

Answer (score 0):

I solved!

There were a digit error in my url.py Now it work